# 3D vision on ATI cards

Tags: 3d-graphics

I've got an ati radeon HD4890 Graphics card,and I want to buy a 3D monitor,with I can everything do in 3D.
My question is that:Can I run the 3D vision anyway with this card??

Answer (score 1):

> 3D vision

3D Vision is an nVidia technology. For an ATi solution, you'll need quite a [lot of proprietary stuff](http://www.xbitlabs.com/news/video/display/20100324235120_ATI_Radeon_Finally_Supports_Stereoscopic_3D_Output.html).

> In order to enjoy stereoscopic 3D gaming or to convert 2D movies to stereo 3D formats, users of ATI Radeon HD graphics cards will have to acquire third-party hardware and software.
>
> Stereo 3D solution from DDD requires a special 3D starter pack ($199) that includes two pairs of wireless 3D active shutter glasses, one 3D transmitter, a CD containing the TriDef 3D Experience software for Windows XP/Vista/7 and an activation code for the TriDef 3D Experience. In addition, end-users need to own an output device supported by DDD, the list of which at present is generally limited to various HDTVs as well as one Hyundai P240W 24” display for whopping $2199. Even though the software from DDD automatically converts video games to stereo 3D format, for the best possible experience the company recommends to download special profiles for new games.
>
> iZ3D’s stereoscopic solution is relatively well known. It requires a proprietary 22” monitor (1680x1050, 5ms, 60Hz, 700:1) from iZ3D which costs $349 which comes with two pairs of proprietary polarized glasses. In fact, iZ3D also offers to output 3D content for viewing in shutter glasses, but for that end-users will have to pay $49. While the latter option seems to be rather interesting, since iZ3D does not provide a list of compatible 3D glasses and displays, it seems that it is still limited to the company’s very own display.